# Dialogflow - How Would I Go About Getting The Context From Fulfilment For First Call?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk

So I am stumped on an issue that I'm finding troublesome to overcome. My agent directly talks to my server which in turn controls certain devices by being the middle man. When I say "Talk to {Agent Name}" then this is fine because the fulfilment Welcome from the server returns a response and a bunch of contexts (based) on devices states which I can follow up in the next call. The problem is when I say "Tell {Agent Name} to do some action" then it will resort to a fallback because it doesn't have any contexts for the states of such devices.

I need a way to find out the states from the fulfilment prior to trying an intent as the intent I'm trying to execute may have an input context and will be skipped as there are no assigned contexts on the initial call (considering i'm trying the "tell {agent name} ....". I prefer to have the tell / ask command for simple commands as calling the welcome takes time and you have to wait for the response then execute the command but is a pain for simplistic commands. I also need these contexts on the intents as alot of other intents have similar phrases that shouldn't be called if the states for them aren't relevant.

Answer (score 1):

A tricky chicken and egg problem, isn't it!

I think the best solution we have is to create Intents that serve as these welcoming intents (you'll mark them as welcome Intents as well) without the Contexts being available. You'll also set them as a lower priority than the ones that actually do the work.

Then, in the handlers for these Intents, you first get the information you need and set the Contexts that are relevant for them, and then do the work and return the response. "Doing the work" can either be calling the same backend functions and returning the results, or using the [Detect Intent API](https://dialogflow.com/docs/sdks#detect_intent_and_agent_apis), which might look something like this:

1. Build the [request](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/api-v2/rpc/google.cloud.dialogflow.v2#google.cloud.dialogflow.v2.DetectIntentRequest) to the API that includes the session you have, the Contexts that you have set, and the original text from the user
2. Send that to [DetectIntentRequest](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/api-v2/rpc/google.cloud.dialogflow.v2#google.cloud.dialogflow.v2.Sessions.DetectIntent). This will go through normal Dialogflow processing, should detect the Intent to be used, and call the appropriate webhook with this Intent. You'll then process this using fulfillment as normal and return your results.
3. Use the values from the [response](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/api-v2/rpc/google.cloud.dialogflow.v2#google.cloud.dialogflow.v2.DetectIntentResponse) (including the `output_contexts`, and `webhook_payload` fields) to build the response from the original webhook that was called.

There are caveats with the latter approach - most notably that you are still limited in how much time the original/welcoming webhook has to complete the task - usually about 5 seconds. So your second webhook has to complete in less than this to allow enough time for the original one to do its work.